# Summing up the rows that have the same name awk

Tags: awk

I have three rows.
First and second row has the numbers, and the third row has the name.
Using awk, how to sum all the numbers related to the name. Names might be random,
so I probably need a variable in that matter. For example it might be looking like this

```
100   221   dog
121   324   cat
42    4341  fish
12    23    cat
2134  424   dog
```

so the output should some all the numbers from row 1 and 2 for all occurences of dog, cat, and fish.
smthg like

```
dog 2879
cat 480
fish 4383
```

Comment: The sample input has 5 rows and 3 columns.  The statement "I have three rows" is an incorrect usage of the word "row".

Answer (score 4):

try this one-liner:

```
awk '{a[$3]+=($1+$2)}END{for(x in a)print x, a[x]}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
{
   name[$3] += $1 + $2
}
END { for (n in name) { print n, name[n]; } } ' datafile
```

Comment: Why the use of int() on the additions and the trailing semi-colon on the print?

Comment: int() is incorrect for this answer. The semi-colon is habit for separating multiple statements. In this case it is superfluous.

Comment: Got it. I thought maybe the int() calls did something to guarantee `a += b + c` behaves like `a += (b + c)` as opposed to `(a += b) + c`. I did suspect the semi-colon was superfluous.

Comment: int() returns the integer value. Would have been appropriate if the brief had asked for integers - but it didn't!